# How to copy Kannada text in photoshop using Doc

Tags: adobe-photoshop

We have doc files with Kannada text now we want to copy same text to Photoshop CS5. But on copying text it loses it formatting and whole meaning of the word changes. Please help

Regards,
Megan

Comment: I think you need to re-write your question as it doesn't make much sense. Not to me anyway.

Comment: A screenshot of "Kannada" would help for future reference.

Comment: @go-meek: [Kannada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada_script) is an Indian script.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I know that, but obviously that could be confusing here among all the font related questions. That's why I mentioned "future reference"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use InDesign instead? InDesign will likely have better support for a font that changes the displayed characters based on what is typed, as Japanese/Chinese and I'm assuming Kannada does.

InDesign also has Place/Import text, that should retain more of the original Word doc, as opposed to Photoshop that basically pastes plain text into a text box.

Also, maybe look into plugins or ensure your language pack is installed for both Windows and Adobe products.